# Creating conditional Makefiles with different compilers, C++ and CUDA

Tags: c++, makefile, compilation, cuda

I've been trying to create a `Makefile` that does the following. I have a `C++` program that calls `CUDA` functions, so I've got a set of `.cpp` and `.cu` files, with all `CUDA` kernels in the `.cu` files.

For every kernel call, I also have a CPU version of that function, so I have code in my `.cpp` files that looks like this

```
if (with_cuda)
{
    call_kernel(parameters);
}
else
{
    call_cpu_function(parameters);
}
```

The `call_kernel` function is defined in the `.cu` files and then calls the actual kernel `kernel<<<X,X>>>(...)`.

I want to be able to compile my program in a system without either a `GPU` or the `CUDA` toolkit. I can easily encapsulate the functions that will call kernels with some macro, for instance, the code above might look like

```
if (with_cuda)
{
#ifdef WITH_CUDA
    call_kernel(parameters);
#endif
}
else
{
    call_cpu_function(parameters);
}
```

And then compile either by `g++ files.cpp` without `CUDA` support, or `nvcc files.cpp other_files.cu -DWITH_CUDA`

And I should encapsulate all other includes to `CUDA` libraries and so on with the same macro `#ifdef...`

How would I make a `Makefile` that looks for the `CUDA` toolkit installed and then does a compilation with `nvcc`, or with `g++` if it's not installed? I've looked into either writing a `Makefile` directly, using cmake, or autoconf with a configure script, but I'm quite lost, so I'm open to using any other method that might be preferable.

Additionally, if that macro encapsulation of every call to a kernel is not the standard or the best way to do this kind of thing, I'm also happy to change how I'm approaching this. I can see a potential issue of having to do an `if` statement for each call as in the code above besides the macro `ifdef`, so I might compile without `CUDA`. Still, then the bool `with_cuda` is set to true for whatever reason, and no function is called, so I can see why this might not be a good solution.

Comment: Doing this using CMake should be relatively straightforrward, see the [`FindCUDAToolkit`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCUDAToolkit.html) command, which populates `CUDAToolkit_FOUND`.

Comment: the makefiles that come with [the CUDA samples](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples) may be of interest.  I'm not suggesting they do this precisely, but they have enough conditional framework to probably give you some ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to jump through all of these hoops, like conditionally-compiling the same file with different compilers, or spelling out an if-cuda-else condition in many locations. Instead, consider using linking mechanisms.

So, when in your C++ file, you have a:

```
do_stuff(params);
```

call - only provide a declaration of this function, but no definition.

Now, either manually in your `Makefile` - or better yet, or auto-generated `Makefile`, see below - you choose between one of two possibilities:

- Compile a `.cu` file with the kernel and a `do_stuff()` host-side wrapper.
- Compile a `.cpp` file with a CPU-based implementation of `do_stuff()`

... and link the object file with calls `do_stuff()` with either one implementation or the other.

Here's how you would do this with CMake: You write this `CMakeLists.txt` file in your project directory:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
include(CheckLanguage)

project(myapp LANGUAGES CXX)

add_executable(myapp calls_dostuff.cpp) 

check_language(CUDA)
if (CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER)
    enable_language(CUDA)
    add_dependencies(myapp dostuff_impl_calling_gpu_kernel.cu) 
else()
    add_dependencies(myapp dostuff_cpu_impl.cpp) 
endif()
```

... and then invoke:

```
cmake -B my_build_path -S project_dir_path -G "Unix Makefiles"
```

to generate a `Makefile` into `my_build_path` for a project locate at `project_dir_path`.

Comment: Thank you! This seems much more professional and less prone to error than what I was doing.

Answer (score 1):

A little hacky, but:

```
ifeq ($(call,$(shell which nvcc))$(.SHELLSTATUS),0)
# Have NVCC
else
# No NVCC
endif
```

This runs `which nvcc`, and checks if it finds any executable.

`$(shell )` runs a shell command and returns whatever it prints to stdout. `$(call, )` is  hacky way to discard that return value, since we don't need it for anything, and only care about the exit code. `$(.SHELLSTATUS)` returns the exit code of the last `$(shell )` call. `ifeq` then compares it for equality with `0`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, einpoklum's answer seems better but I might use this more hacky method for smaller projects